# All elements of fragment are null after it is added/replaced in activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, fragmentmanager

I have an activity in which I want to replace a fragment. The code that I am using is given below:

```
 ResultFragment resultFragment = new ResultFragment();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();                      
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction()                  
 .replace(R.id.fl_act_events_view_container, resultFragment, "ResultFragment")
 .commit();
 fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
 resultFragment.updateUI(result);
```

I execute this code in onCreate() method of Activity.

updateUI() method simply updates the values of all elements on the Result Fragment based on "result" string. The problem that I am having is, all the elements are null when updateUI() is called.

For example, ResultFragment has a TextView name. When I do:

```
 name.setText(result.getName());
```

I am getting NullPointerException as name is null. Similarly for all other UI elements of ResultFragment.

I am not able to understand what is the issue? I have tried multiple methods but nothing seem to work. Like, I also did the following:

```
  Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ResultFragment");
    if(fragment instanceof ResultFragment){
        resultFragment = (ResultFragment) fragment;
        resultFragment.updateUI(result);
    }
```

but the same problem persists.

Then I tried:

```
    ResultFragment resultFragment = new ResultFragment();
    replaceFragment(resultFragment);
  ResultFragment.updateUI(result);


    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
      if(fragment==null) return;

      FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
      FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
      ft.replace(R.id.fl_act_events_view_container, fragment);
      ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
      ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

but nothing works. Somebody please explain how should I be able to call updateUI method after replacing the fragment in activity

Comment: Can you show your fragment code, what's inside your fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You can update views under `updateUI()` by putting codes under `updateUI()` inside a thread. E.g. `Runnable`

Inside Fragment, declare an object and invoke in activity.

```
public Runnable mRunnableUpdate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateUI();
    }
};
```

Activity
    `mRunnableUpdate.run();`

Answer (score 0):

So, after spending a lot of time, I finally realized that updateUI was being called before all the elements were getting initialized. It was more of a timing issue. I just needed to ensure that all the elements are initialized before calling updateUI and thus it solved the problem.